# .bash_profile wrecks my PATH, but .bashrc

Tags: android, macos, bash

i've been using `.bashrc` (happily) for a long time, but when i tried to add 
`export PATH="/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/"` to my path, it wouldn't work... i figured i'd add it to a .bash_profile file, but whenever i run my terminal with `.bash_profile`, no commands work not `ls` and none of the commands i put in my `.bash_profile` path. 
i would continue to use `.bashrc`, but another script (one that i shouldn't edit) uses adb, and i can't get `.bashrc` to see it for some reason.. (adb is in `/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/`

what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the `/Users/.../` path to your already existing `$PATH`

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/"
```

Your command says the `$PATH` variable will only be 1 "folder" `/Users/...`. But `$PATH` is in fact already defined and used. So you have to concatenate the new "folder" to the list of folders in `$PATH`. If you do `echo $PATH` you will see this list.

If you want to add more than 1 path, you can still do that in one expression:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/:/Users/sam/bin/:/a/third/addition/"
```

Comment: thanks! that fixed the .bash_profile problem, however for some reason i still can't get adb to run.. this is my current .bash_profile
`export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb"
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx/tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/sam/bin/"
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx"`

sorry for the formatting, not used to comments yet

Comment: @sam_r well, that's another question. But be sure that adb is in this folder, and you didn't make a typo when adding it to the PATH. And that you have the right to execute it too.

Comment: @sam_r Use the suggestion from the answer. None of your lines add the directory that adb is in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are completely overriding the value of PATH. By default PATH contains references to the binary files, which includes the commands. As you are forcing the value of PATH without preserving the current value your terminal is not finding any other than

```
"/Users/sam/bin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/"
```

When modifying the path variable it's recommended to do it in the next way - at least you are sure that the forced value won't break the shell:

```
PATH=$PATH:New_Reference  # Colon is the separator of the values
export PATH
```